# Core Data Crash "External data reference can't find underlying file."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, encryption, core-data

The app has CoreData storage where (among other data) images can be stored. As images can be of different sizes, the `Allows External Storage` setting has been enabled.

Sometimes, the app crushes with the error mentioned in the title:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException External data reference can't find underlying file.

This happens only in the released app, only for some share of the users. I have not been able to reproduce it ever (setting `Optimization level` to `Fastest, Smallest [-Os]` did not help in reproducing as well).

What can be seen from the Sentry (used for reporting crashes):

- it happens when the app tries to retrieve the object from the Core Data; the object has `data` property which is the image and has the `Allows External Storage` setting enabled
- it happens when the app is in background (usually more than couple of minutes, but can happen quicker)
- it is not on the main thread.

To allow accessing storage from different threads, the following has been implemented:

```
private var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        if Thread.current.isMainThread {
            return persistentContainer.viewContext
        }
        return backgroundContext // this is initialised once with persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
 }
```

Another potentially useful piece of information is that protection is enabled for the CoreData:

```
// encrypt core data contents
// FileProtectionType.complete means that core data contents will be encrypted at all times when the device is locked
container.persistentStoreDescriptions.forEach {
     $0.setOption(FileProtectionType.complete as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey)
}
```

Any help on the ideas of how to fix this crash will be more that welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand why you need `context` implementation that returns either view context or background context. You can use view context directly without dispatching work with `perform` given that you're on a main thread, however for background context, you always have to use `perform` as it's impossible to make assumption about the current context (queue/thread). Also persistent containers support `performBackgroundTask`. So maybe the culprit is in how you interact with contexts. I don't have much code to look at so just throwing some ideas.

Comment: We don't always want to access CoreData on main thread. To avoid problems, we have made a dedicated queue. Inside that queue that dedicated context is used. I have specified that detail simply to let know that it's not mere non-main-thread issue (unless I am missing something else, of course).

Comment: That's not how concurrency works with Core Data. If you're using a dedicated queue and not `perform` or `performAndWait` (or `performBackgroundTask`) then you're setting yourself up for concurrency problems. Core Data doesn't care about your dedicated queue, only its own queues.

Comment: This is something I will definitely consider and investigate. Actually, thanks for this comment.
Still, I don't think it's the reason for this particular problem, because a) it always happens in background b) it happens only to images.
I assume concurrency problems wouldn't care for application mode or data type?

Comment: Excerpt from documentation:

`Core Data uses thread (or serialized queue) confinement to protect managed objects and managed object contexts (see Core Data Programming Guide). A consequence of this is that a context assumes the default owner is the thread or queue that creates it. Don’t, therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to another.` Either way I would suggest to use `perform` or `performAndWait`. I can see how concurrency issues could cause inconsistent state especially when it comes to storing files on disk.

Comment: I'm seeing the same crash in my Core Data app with the same setup in App Center. I don't think it's related to concurrency as I used `context.performAndWait` in this call stack. Also, I've been testing a lot during the development. This kind of crash never happened.

Comment: Did you locate the problem here? @YevgeniyLeychenko

Comment: Not exactly. I have a feeling it is connected with the app being in background, and I am still getting these crashes from time to time.